# How to read specific columns from a Parquet file in Java

Tags: apache, parquet, columnstore

I am using a WriteSupport that knows how to write my custom object 'T' into Parquet. I am interested in only reading 2 or 3 **specific columns** out of 100 columns of my custom object that are written into the Parquet file.

Most examples online extend ReadSupport and read the entire record. Want to accomplish this **without using things like Spark, Hive, Avro, Thrift, etc.**

**An example in Java, which reads selected columns of a custom object in Parquet**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post may help.

[Read specific column from Parquet without using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613403/read-specific-column-from-parquet-without-using-spark?rq=1)

> If you just want to read specific columns, then you need to set a read schema on the configuration that the ParquetReader builder accepts. (This is also known as a projection).
>
> In your case you should be able to call .withConf(conf) on the AvroParquetReader builder class, and in the conf you pass in, invoke conf.set(ReadSupport.PARQUET_READ_SCHEMA, schema) where schema is a avro schema in String form.