# Is it possible to filter output column returned by AvroParquetReader?

Tags: java, avro, parquet

I'm writing an app to store/read files in parquet format. I'm using AvroParquetReader/AvroParquetWriter.

I see is possible to add filtering condition with FilterPredicate, but is it possible to also filter which columns to extract?

Eg, my records stores columns A,B,C,D but I just want to extract A,B without extracting C,D.

Thanks

Comment: Might be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112261/139595

Comment: Thanks, but it does not works.